# Django cms creation wizard form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-cms, django-widget

I have an Article model with `CharFields`,`models.DateTimeField` and `FilerFileField`. I create form like this:

```
class ArticleWizardForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        exclude = []

    class Media:
        js = 'admin/js/jquery.init.js', #this not working
```

and creation wizard like this:

```
class ArticleWizard(Wizard):
    pass

article_wizard = ArticleWizard(
    title="Article",
    weight=200,
    form=ArticleWizardForm,
    description="Create a new Article",
)

wizard_pool.register(article_wizard)
```

It works fine with trivial `CharFields` but `models.DateTimeField` and `FilerFileField` don't have same widgets like in django admin. You can see differences in the following screenshot (Django admin on right)! I figured out that django JS is not loaded so I add it to `Media`. However it wasn't added to the template. So I hard code it to `cms\wizards\base.html` and `jquery.init.js`  was successfully loaded but widgets always look like on the image.

[image: Screenshot]

Question is, how can I reach same look and functionality in creation wizard like in django admin?

And why media is not loaded in template?

original `cms\wizards\base.html`

```
{% block extrahead %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static_with_version "cms/js/modules/jquery.noconflict.pre.js" %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static_with_version "cms/js/libs/jquery.min.js" %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static_with_version "cms/js/modules/jquery.noconflict.post.js" %}"></script>
    {{ form.media }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47410404/7639622 but it should work with cms version 3.10