# Django-Filer FilerImageField how to use widget outside admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-cms, django-filer

I want to use the `FilerImageField`in one of my model field and want the user to edit outside the admin area but when I try to load it, the widget doesn't work correctly and in the browser console I get and error in the javascript generated:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery' of undefined
```

In here:

```
            <script type="text/javascript" id="id_featured_image_javascript">
                django.jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                    var plus = django.jQuery('#add_id_featured_image');
                    if (plus.length){
                        plus.remove();
                    }
                    // Delete this javascript once loaded to avoid the "add new" link duplicates it
                    django.jQuery('#id_featured_image_javascript').remove();
                });
            </script>
```

The field in my model is defined like this:

```
article_image = FilerImageField(db_column="ARTICLE_IMAGE",
                                 verbose_name=_('Article Image'),
                                 related_name='IPP_ARTICLE_IMAGE')
```

The field appears like this:

[image: Field]

Do you have any idea why I can't use this field widget outside the admin? Do I need to set some configuration for this?

Thank you :)

Comment: Hello Patricia, I've answered on the Github ticket.

Comment: @Paulo can you post a link?

Comment: actually I tracked it down -- for those following along, the short answer is that it's not supported as an extra-admin upload widget: https://github.com/divio/django-filer/issues/894

Comment: how to access image URL inside models or templates of filer fields

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add `{{ form.media }}` in your html file, just after the tag `<form>` and `{% csrf_token %}`. Then extend the media class in your `ModelForm` of forms.py as explained by SteinRobert on Github issue: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/6028. It works perfect! Thanks Stein!

Answer (score 0):

First create `forms.py` then

```
from django import forms
..............

class MyImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModelName
        fields = ['article_image']        
        
class Media:
    extend = False
    css = {
        'all': [
            'filer/css/admin_filer.css',
        ]
    }
    js = (
        'admin/js/core.js',
        'admin/js/jquery.js',
        'admin/js/jquery.init.js',
        'admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js',
        'admin/js/actions.js',
        'admin/js/urlify.js',
        'admin/js/prepopulate.js',
        'filer/js/libs/dropzone.min.js',
        'filer/js/addons/dropzone.init.js',
        'filer/js/addons/popup_handling.js',
        'filer/js/addons/widget.js',
        'admin/js/related-widget-wrapper.js',
    )
```

After that run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

in your terminal for collect all css and js files. Then `views.py`

```
..............
from .forms import MyImageForm

def (or) class imageView(....):
    ...............
    context['form'] = MyImageForm()
    ...............
```

In the end `index.html`

```
...............
...............

<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
................
................

<label for="image">Image</label>
{{ form.article_image }}

<button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>

{{ form.media }}

<script src="{% static 'admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'admin/js/actions.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'admin/js/urlify.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'admin/js/prepopulate.js' %}"></script>
```